# TIA Portal V16 CAx-Operations - Siemens TIA Openness User Group not found

Tags: c#, siemens

I have problems exporting CAx-Data from the Siemens TIA Portal V16. I am using the following openness code:

```
CaxProvider provider = tiaPortalProject.GetService<CaxProvider>();

FileInfo pathAMLfile = new FileInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo pathLOGfile = new FileInfo(@"C:\");

provider.Export(tiaPortalProject, pathAMLfile, pathLOGfile);
```

The following error message occurs:

The CAx operation cannot be started. Check if the ‘Siemens TIA Openness’ group exists on the system.'

I followed all the steps given in the documentation  to create a new Openness User, and restarted the pc serveral times (using a virtual machine in this case).

Documentation:
https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/mdm/109773802?c=101778035467&lc=en-DE

I am logged in as a member of  the Siemens TIA Openness Group. The dialog is in german but you should get it from the picture. I had to blur the acutal user name.

[image: System Group Siemens TIA Openness]

But it still does not work. All other openness operations work well. Can someone help? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried previous Openness DLLs (e.g. 15.1?)  Also, have you confirmed that the logged in user is running the application, or another user?

Comment: Yes, the logged on user is running the application. I'll try it with the 15.1 dll.